# "Must be able to" necessity reference

Tags: semantics

"User must be able to login through google SSO"

Does this rule express a necessity for the user or application? I mean that the USER must have the ability for login, or application must let users to login through google?

Comment: It implies both.  The user must have a Google SSO account and the application must have the capacity to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without context, it's impossible to say. Ask for clarification.

It could mean:

- Application users must have a Google account they can use for authentication.
- The application must allow Google SSO for users who have it.
- Only Google SSO will be allowed for application login.

It could also mean something else entirely. Badly-written requirements are regrettably common.

Comment: Actually, the sentence *itself* is fine—so long as it's placed within a context that makes its meaning clear. (In other words, it's ambiguous on its own, but it would be perfectly acceptable if previous sentences were talking about something that explained the meaning.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it stresses that the system/application should provide a way for the user to login through SSO. So the necessity is for the application, not the user.